# For.. in loop cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, for-loop, properties, undefined, console.log

```js
var table = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers");

function seppuku() {
  for (let i in table) {
    table[i].style.color = "red";
  }
}
seppuku();
```

```html
<div class="numbers">1</div>
<div class="numbers">2</div>
<div class="numbers">3</div>
```

So here's my code. My problem is: Why console.log communicate "Cannot set property 'color' of undefined" after seppuku() function invoking?

It's not like var table is not defined! Actually, it has global scope and should be available for 'for.. in' loop. Moreover, this function **works**, chosen elements has color: red property now. How that works despite the communicate in console?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea - [watch the output when you log `table[0]` to the console](https://jsfiddle.net/38m95eok/2/).

Comment: Instead of for-in loop use for loop

Comment: Try to `console.log(table)` and you'll understand what your loop is iterating

Comment: because the result of `document.querySelectorAll(".numbers")` it's an array like object,if you would use the for loop you must convert to array
`var table = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers");`
`table = Array.prototype.slice.call(table)`  see https://fiddle.jshell.net/fe23Lr42/1/

Answer (score 3):

You used `for...in` statement which iterates over the enumerable properties of an object. In this case, `table` object contains following enumerable properties.

```
{
  "0": <div class="numbers">1</div>,
  "1": <div class="numbers">2</div>,
  "2": <div class="numbers">3</div>,
  "length": 3,
  "item": function item() { [native code] },
  "entries": function entries() { [native code] },
  "forEach": function forEach() { [native code] },
  "keys": function keys() { [native code] },
  "values": function values() { [native code] }
}
```

So in the 4th iteration, `i` becomes `length` and table['length'].style throws an error. We can use `forEach` method to resolve this issue.

```js
var table = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers");

(function seppuku() {
   table.forEach(function(item) {
   item.style.color = "red";
   });
})();
```

```html
<div class="numbers">1</div>
<div class="numbers">2</div>
<div class="numbers">3</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've just wanted to get deeper into ES6 (I knew typical "for loop" method). But, yeah, definitely I'll use working one ;)

Comment: I added more explanation. Please let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Using `let i in table` has last element for `i` as `length` so it results to `table['length'].style.color = "red";` which is incorrect as there is no element `table['length']` and returns `undefined`. Better way is to just loop through the `length` of `table` which will be 0, 1 and 2.

```js
var table = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers");

function seppuku() {
  for (var i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
    table[i].style.color = "red";
  }
}
seppuku();
```

```html
<div class="numbers">1</div>
<div class="numbers">2</div>
<div class="numbers">3</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've just wanted to get deeper into ES6 (I knew typical "for loop" method). But, yeah, definitely I'll use working one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple for loop instead of for..in

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="numbers">1</div>
<div class="numbers">2</div>
<div class="numbers">3</div>

<script>

function seppuku() {

var table = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers"); 
  for (let i=0;i<table.length;i++ ) {
   
    table[i].style.color = "red";
  }
}
seppuku();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```