# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined // for and while loop difference?

Tags: javascript, loops, typeerror

I am a newbie to JS and just took a first step of programming.

i am making a simple webpage with a button that allows text, links and background to change color.

working well but on consonle screen, i got an error message.

i look through same issues but still don't get it.

```html
<body>
    <h1><a href='index.com'>WEB</a></h1>

    <input type='button' value='night' onclick="
    let target = document.querySelector('body');
    if(this.value === 'night'){
      target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      target.style.color = 'white';
      this.value = 'day';

      links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      for (link in links){
          links[link].style.color = 'red';
      }

    }
    else {
      target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      target.style.color = 'black';
      this.value = 'night';  
    }
    ">

    <ol>
        <li><a href='1.html')>HTML</a>></li>
        <li><a href='2.html')>CSS</a></li> 
        <li><a href='3.html')>JavaScript</a></li>   
    </ol>
    adsf
</body>
```

but the thing is when using 'while loop instead of 'for loop like below. no bug.

```
  links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  i = 0;
  while (i < links.length){
      links[i].style.color = 'red';
      i++;
```

what's going on here?
somehow by using 'while loop', i solved it. but  i still  don't get why 'while loop' got no error, when
'for loop' has 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined' error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For.. in loop cannot set property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905877/for-in-loop-cannot-set-property-of-undefined)

Comment: Change `for (link in links){` to `for(let link=0;link<links.length;link++){`

Answer (score 1):

Because when using `for..in` you get one item from an array at a time, not the index

```js
for (let link in links){
    link.style.color = 'red';
}
```

when using `while` you have an index to iterate over the array (let it be `i`)
`i` represent the current index of your iteration, so accessing an item in array would work like `links[i]`

Comment: No, in a `for...in` loop, you get an enumerable property of the object at a time. This will also cause errors.

Comment: sorry but accessing object properties need `Object.keys` to work as you want (ex. ```let obj = { hello: 'world'} ;for(let key of Object.keys(obj)) console.log(key)
```)

Comment: I don't really see how that has anything to do with this question or your answer. Assuming `querySelectorAll()` does find elements, the first iteration of your loop the `link` will be the string `"0"`. A string doesn't have a `style` attribute so `style` will be undefined and reading `color` from `undefined` will throw an error. [Try it yourself](https://jsfiddle.net/xsp76bdc/). This answer is just plain wrong.